# MAAS error while commisioning a physical server

Tags: maas

While making commision for the added server, I got the error below:

```
Failed to query node's BMC - (root) - No rack controllers can access the BMC of node node-1
```

Note: I used MAAS version 3.1 and a physical server.

Comment: Hello. Need some details. What Ubuntu version is being used? What was the exact command you used?

Comment: ubuntu 18.04 , i didn't use commmand , i just try to add a physical server as a machine to make comision on it then the commision failed with the above error.